# Detect circular objects with specific color

Tags: python, opencv

My goal is detecting all the purple pollen in the image below and put the letter "P" in it. 
[image]

But the result shows that it always mistakes a black area.

[image]

Changing the radius in circle detection would not help because I still have lots of similar images to go. So what should I do to better it?

Here is my code:

```
# coding: utf-8


import cv2
import numpy as np


path = "./sample.JPG"
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX

def image_resize(image, width = None, height = None, inter = cv2.INTER_AREA):
    # initialize the dimensions of the image to be resized and
    # grab the image size
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    # if both the width and height are None, then return the
    # original image
    if width is None and height is None:
        return image

    # check to see if the width is None
    if width is None:
        # calculate the ratio of the height and construct the
        # dimensions
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)

    # otherwise, the height is None
    else:
        # calculate the ratio of the width and construct the
        # dimensions
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    # resize the image
    resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = inter)

    # return the resized image
    return resized

iml = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = image_resize(iml,width=960)

cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
#cv2.GaussianBlur(cimg, (9,9),3)
cimg = cv2.medianBlur(cimg,5)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cimg[:,:,0],cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,cimg.shape[0]/16,param1=15,param2=20,minRadius=18,maxRadius=38)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))[0,:]

for i in circles:
     cv2.putText(img,'P',(i[0],i[1]), font, 0.5,(0,255,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imwrite("./output.jpg",img)
```

In addition, I also tried using color detection since all I want to detect have the same color (purple). I follow the [instructions here](https://henrydangprg.com/2016/06/26/color-detection-in-python-with-opencv/amp/)
but it still didn't work.

Comment: Split the problem in two parts: (a) filter the color (make every other color black), and (b) detect circles.

Comment: Similar to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535609/circle-detection-without-overlaping/52536189#52536189

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can detect the purple directly in HSV color space if you can carefully choose the right `hsv range`. This colormap is taken from my other answers.

[image]

I select `Hue(120,160), Saturation(180, 255), Value(50, 255)` for `this task` to get the mask.

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (120, 180, 50), (160, 255, 255))
```

Then you can do the processing on the mask.

[image]

Links maybe helpful:

1. [How to define a threshold value to detect only green colour objects in an image :Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image/47483966#47483966)
2. [Choosing the correct upper and lower HSV boundaries for color detection with`cv::inRange` (OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv/48367205#48367205)
3. [RGB range for color red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229126/rgb-range-for-color-red/51230291#51230291)

Comment: These values are better for purple: H(126,145), S(142, 255), V(57, 255). Try using this script to easily find HSV ranges: https://github.com/smeschke/juggling/blob/master/hsv_color_picker.py

Comment: HSV is a bit difficult to use because the hue wraps at red. If you don't get good results with HSV I'd suggest trying YUV or LAB and creating a bounding box for the purple shade you want in the UV (or AB) planes.

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me the full code? I don't know why but I couldn't do circle detection for the mask, cause my last purpose is to write the letter P into the pollen.

Comment: Hey my code worked now but I still don't understand the way to find the range of purple (I don't get the pic you attached). Could you explain more?