# Using circle detection and color detection to recognize an object

Tags: python, opencv

I am using color detection (purple in particular) and circle detection to detect pollen object (the purple circular one) in the image below.

[image]

Then I write the letter "P" in the object detected. Unfortunately it didn't work as I expected.

[image]

I can fix it if I change the radius, but it is not a good idea since I still have lots of similar images with various radius to process. i think the main point is how to know the exact range of the purple in this image. Generally, I want to know how to get the range of an arbitrary color in an image. Some people gave me a sample code but it didn't work well.

Here is my program.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


# In[2]:

path = "./sample.JPG"
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX


# In[3]:

def image_resize(image, width = None, height = None, inter = cv2.INTER_AREA):
    # initialize the dimensions of the image to be resized and
    # grab the image size
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    # if both the width and height are None, then return the
    # original image
    if width is None and height is None:
        return image

    # check to see if the width is None
    if width is None:
        # calculate the ratio of the height and construct the
        # dimensions
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)

    # otherwise, the height is None
    else:
        # calculate the ratio of the width and construct the
        # dimensions
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    # resize the image
    resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = inter)

    # return the resized image
    return resized


# In[4]:

iml = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = image_resize(iml,width=960)


# In[5]:

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv = cv2.medianBlur(hsv,5)
#mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (120, 180, 50), (160, 255, 255))
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (105, 100,50), (160, 255, 255))

#mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (126, 142, 57), (145, 255, 255))
#cv2.GaussianBlur(cimg, (9,9),3)
#cimg = cv2.medianBlur(cimg,5)
output = cv2.bitwise_and(hsv, hsv, mask = mask)
#circles = cv2.HoughCircles(mask[:,:,0],cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,mask.shape[0]/16,param1=15,param2=20,minRadius=18,maxRadius=38)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(output[:,:,0],cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,output.shape[0]/16,param1=15,param2=20,minRadius=15,maxRadius=30)
print(len(circles))
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))[0,:]


# In[6]:

for i in circles:
     cv2.putText(img,'P',(i[0],i[1]), font, 0.5,(0,255,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)


# In[7]:

cv2.imwrite("./result.jpg",img)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535609/circle-detection-without-overlaping/52536422#52536422

Comment: The problem are not the same. I suggest reading carefully. Thank you.

Comment: Try narrowing down the `cv2.inRange` parameters

Answer (score 1):

Note that this answer is not meant to be a solution but maybe a new point of view to achieve your task. Even though it may work in some cases it will probably not be robust enough for automating any processes. That being said, the problem with converting to HSV colorspace is that if the image (as in your case) has similar color objects drawn on it then it will be difficult to distiguish one object from another with `cv2.inRange()`. I tried to alter your code a bit and made an example on how I would approach this.

First you could try to look for all contours after OTSU theresholding on the image and filter the biggest (donut) and other small ones out with a criteria of your choosing.

Once you have that you can make a ROI around that contour. Then I would try to perform the `cv2.inRange()` on each ROI.

After that I would search for contours again on each ROI and count white pixels or make a "circularity" criteria for contours. If they pass that means that it has a lot of pixels in range and draw the letter T. Hope it helps a bit. Cheers!

Example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


# In[2]:

path = "./purplecirc4.JPG"
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX


# In[3]:

def image_resize(image, width = None, height = None, inter = cv2.INTER_AREA):
    # initialize the dimensions of the image to be resized and
    # grab the image size
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    # if both the width and height are None, then return the
    # original image
    if width is None and height is None:
        return image

    # check to see if the width is None
    if width is None:
        # calculate the ratio of the height and construct the
        # dimensions
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)

    # otherwise, the height is None
    else:
        # calculate the ratio of the width and construct the
        # dimensions
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    # resize the image
    resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = inter)

    # return the resized image
    return resized


# In[4]:

iml = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = image_resize(iml,width=960)

# Threshold with OTSU to get all contours
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Empty list for contours that could be positive
ROIs=[]


# Append possible contours to list
# (I have selected height to eliminate unwanted noise)
for cnt in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    if 200 > h > 20:
        x1 = x-20
        x2 = x+w+20
        y1 = y-20
        y2 = y+h+20
        roi = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        ROIs.append(roi)

# Iterate through list of ROIS and transform to HSV
# (I made a little adjustment in values )
for i in ROIs:
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(i,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (115,100,50), (160,255,255))
    # Search for contours on every ROI in list and select the biggest one
    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    # Draw them whole on hsv then transform to gray and perform OTSU threshold and search for contoures
    cv2.drawContours(hsv, [cnt], 0, 255, -1)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    # Make a "roundness" criterion and draw the letter
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
    radius = perimeter/(2*np.pi)
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    circ = 4*area/(np.pi*(radius*2)**2)
    if circ > 0.70:
        cv2.putText(i,'P',(int(x+(w/2.5)),int(y+(h/2))), font, 0.5,(0,255,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)

# Display result:
resized = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5) 
cv2.imshow("roi",resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey I copied your code but it didn't work well. There was no "P" like what you shown. Could you check your code again?

Comment: I checked and it works in on my PC. I advise to visualize with cv2.imshow() before and in the for loop for every step (hsv, thresh...) and see what the code does. Note that as I mentioned in the post that this answer is not meant to be a full working solution but maybe a new way of approach to the problem to give you some new idea. Keep in mind that it is hard to produce a full working solution with just one sample image.